# Adding an ImageField to already existing model in django

Tags: python, django

I have followed Django Girls tuorial http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/index.html and successfully created a blog. However I wanted to add an image field to my block, 
Currently my models.py looks like:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    text = models.TextField()
    model_pic= models.ImageField(upload_to = 'blog/images', default='blog/images/already.png')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null =True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def approved_comment(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)

class Comment(models.Model):

    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text =  models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

and my views.py looks like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404 ,redirect

from .models import Post, Comment

from django.utils import timezone
from .forms import PostForm, CommentForm 
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte = timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html',{'posts' : posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk = pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html',{'post':post})

@login_required
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit = False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('blog.views.post_detail', pk=post.pk)

    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('blog.views.post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def post_draft_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=True).order_by('created_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_draft_list.html',{'posts':posts})

@login_required
def post_publish(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.publish()
    return redirect('blog.views.post_detail', pk=pk)

@login_required
def post_remove(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.delete()
    return redirect('blog.views.post_list')

def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit = False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('blog.views.post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request,'blog/add_comment_to_post.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def comment_approve(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    comment.approve()
    return redirect('blog.views.post_detail', pk=comment.post.pk)

@login_required
def comment_remove(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    post_pk = comment.post.pk
    comment.delete()
    return redirect('blog.views.post_detail', pk=post_pk)
```

and my forms.py appears like :

```
from django import forms

from .models import Post, Comment

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'text')

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('author', 'text',)
```

Now Please guide me what changes should I make in model Post and how should I modify the view to get my image rendered and how should I make the template for same

I tried https://coderwall.com/p/bz0sng/simple-django-image-upload-to-model-imagefield but It didn't worked for me.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank You.

Had you need any more information please comment it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, let's go.

When you set a `ImageField()`, you have a `upload_to` attribute. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to):

> A local filesystem path that will be appended to your MEDIA_ROOT setting to determine the value of the url attribute.

So you will have a function to determine a dynamic path where the image will be stored (read the link above for more information).

E.g.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    text = models.TextField()
    model_pic= models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image, default='blog/images/already.png')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null =True)


    def upload_image(self, filename):
        return 'post/{}/{}'.format(self.title, filename)
```

Note that you don't include the `model_pic` in your `fields` of the PostForm. So it will not appear on the template.

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'text', 'model_pic',)
```

Your view will change a little bit:

```
@login_required
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Once you're using an upload, you will use the request.FILES [read more here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES), but let me quote this:

> Note that FILES will only contain data if the request method was POST and the  that posted to the request had enctype="multipart/form-data". Otherwise, FILES will be a blank dictionary-like object.

So on your template, your tag `<form>` will have a attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="">
    {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
```

After all, you can retrieve this image to show in a page. Assuming that you have passed a `post` instance via context to the template:

```
<img src="{{ post.model_pic.url }}" alt="{{ post.title }}" />
```

Comment: Thank you @mazulo . I will implement the changes suggested by you, and will let you know.

Comment: Yes I as making mistake in MEDIA_ROOT, that fixed the problem , thanks